# iOS Comments List View Component

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, open-source, comments

I wanna implement comments view like this:

[image]

Is there any open source project doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do not know about source code but you can create the above UI by customizing UIView or using image whatever you feel as simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [GitHub link](https://github.com/funkyboy/Building-a-Jabber-client-for-iOS) for the SourceCode.

For the tutorial [Refer this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-custom-chat-view-and-emoticons/)